# My code is not running, I am trying to retrieve data from json file. i don't know the problem with my sqlite3 query

Tags: python, sqlite

All of this data has been acquired and its all printing well but cannot be reflected in the database in SQLBrowser. When I printed the value of the variables it was all correct I had been using `conn.commit` at the end of the code. But not even one value is obtained in the sqlite file it produced[The image shows how it looks in the sqlfile][1]

````py
import ssl
import sqlite3
import json

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname= False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

conn = sqlite3.connect('covid.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Covid;
CREATE TABLE Covid (start_date TEXT, end_date TEXT, state TEXT, sex TEXT, age_group TEXT, covid_19_deaths INTEGER, total_deaths INTEGER, pneumonia_deaths INTEGER, influenza_deaths INTEGER, pneumonia_influenza_or_covid INTEGER)''')
conn.commit
hand = open('Covid.json').read()
data = json.loads(hand)

for item in data:
        start_date = item['start_date']
        end_date = item['end_date']
        state = item['state']
        sex = item['sex']
        age_group = item['age_group']
        covid_19_deaths = item['covid_19_deaths']
        total_deaths = item['total_deaths']
        pneumonia_deaths = item['pneumonia_deaths']
        influenza_deaths = item['influenza_deaths']
        pneumonia_influenza_or_covid = item['pneumonia_influenza_or_covid']
        
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Covid (start_date)
                VALUES ( ? )''', (start_date,) )
        cur.execute('''INSERT  INTO Covid (end_date)
                VALUES ( ? )''', ( end_date,) )
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Covid (state)
                VALUES ( ? )''', ( state,) )
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Covid (sex)
                VALUES ( ? )''', ( sex,) )
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Covid (age_group)
                VALUES ( ? )''', ( age_group,) )
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Covid (covid_19_deaths)
                VALUES ( ? )''', ( covid_19_deaths,) )
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Covid (total_deaths)
                VALUES ( ? )''', ( total_deaths,) )
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Covid (pneumonia_deaths)
                VALUES ( ? )''', ( pneumonia_deaths,) )
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Covid (influenza_deaths)
                VALUES ( ? )''', ( influenza_deaths,) )
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Covid (pneumonia_influenza_or_covid)
                VALUES ( ? )''', ( pneumonia_influenza_or_covid,) )
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Covid
                (start_date,end_date,state,sex,age_group,covid_19_deaths,total_deaths,pneumonia_deaths,influenza_deaths,pneumonia_influenza_or_covid ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? ,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''',
        (start_date,end_date,state,sex,age_group,covid_19_deaths,total_deaths,pneumonia_deaths,influenza_deaths,pneumonia_influenza_or_covid ))
        conn.commit```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAdy1.png

I cannot find the mistakes i'm making in the code.
````

Comment: Provide your schema, Python MRE (where is your connection code?), format your code section, so that it is readable.

Answer (score 1):

The code is not complete (no creation / initialisation of the data, and the `cur.execute` statement seems incorrectly indented).

You also don't explain what the exact issue you observe is.

However there is a flagrant issue in your code: you iterate on `data`

```
for item in data:
```

but then rather than use `item` you keep using `data[0]`:

```
start_date = data[0]['start_date']
```

So you're not inserting all the stuff in `data`, you're inserting the first row `len(data)` times.

You also never *call* `commit`, so it's not going to *do* anything:

```
conn.commit
```

PS: I reformatted the post so the code block is correct, you need the opening and closing "triple backticks" to be on their own line e.g.

````
```
for foo in bar:
    ...
```
````

not

````
```for foo in bar:
    ...```
````

which is what you wrote and renders to a broken snippet.